# 4 page maze ft. portals!

Tags: mazes

I found a large 4-page maze that I made a while back. Made entirely with pen and grid paper.

[image: picture of maze]

Here's a digitally scanned and cleaned-up version

[image: digitally edited maze]

Your goal is to find a path from the start to the finish, picking up the key along the way.

Comment: Do the colors mean anything in particular? Or are those the keys?

Comment: @Chipster the colours look like "portals" to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the illustrated paths:

> [image]

We can go:

> Start to Green
>  Green to Purple
>  Purple to Key
>  Key to Purple
>  Purple to Green
>  Green to Blue
>  Blue to Yellow
>  Yellow to Finish

Answer (score 15):

While this maze is already well solved by
[*Avi*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99557/)
and (alternatively)
[*pfg*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100143/18129/)
it also provides an excellent example
for demonstrating a general solving technique
of highlighting some walls in order to divide a maze into sections.
Here are some good places to begin highlighting this maze.

[image]

Normally each of these beginnings would be highlighted much further
before moving on to the next one, culminating with a partitioning into
outlined sections with narrow entries and exits.

> [image]

On this maze these highlit-walled-off sections first make clear
how to reach the **K**ey (black dot), working backward from it.

> • The **K**ey is in a section shared only with a **P**urple portal.
>  
>  • The other **P**urple portal is in a section shared only
>         with **G**reen portal.
>  
>  • The other **G**reen portal can be reached from **S**tart.

Then it is clear how to reach **F**inish, working backward from there.

> • **F**inish is in a section shared only with a **Y**ellow portal.
>  
>  • The other **Y**ellow portal is in a section shared with
>         **R**ed and **B**lue portals.
>  
>  • The other **B**lue portal is in the **G**reen portal’s section
>         accessible from **S**tart.

Note that a shorter path from **S**tart to **F**inish is revealed as well
that uses **R**ed and **Y**ellow portals but fails to visit the **K**ey.

**Some benefits of highlighting maze walls**

- Highlighting any medium-length or long winding wall is useful.
  Interesting branch points along the way may be marked with
  thick **•** dots that are easy to find and continue from later.
- No need for erasing.
  Highlighted walls can only help, as long as highlighting is
  judiciously discontinued in any area that begins to form
  a thicket of highlights,
  in which case the result still causes no harm.
- It is surprisingly easy to scan fairly far ahead
  before deciding to highlight a specific portion of wall.
- Highlighted walls break up a large maze into smaller mazes
  that are each easier to solve.
- Highlighting a wall is a stress-free way, with no chance of mistakes,
  to explore and annotate a maze.
- **Walls reveal much of the methodology behind a maze’s construction.**

Comment: Excellent explaination! Yes this was exactly the first step I did while creating this maze. The sections were intentionally made to be oddly-shaped, to make the maze more difficult

Comment: Thank you making such a fun large maze to analyze, @MrSiliconGuy ,
with enclosed sections and by hand!
I especially appreciate the tempting red (herring) portal,
the way the green-portal sections intertwine to interfere with each other,
and the vast blue-red-yellow portal wilderness covering most of the left
side.  So much variety.
I also appreciate the trouble you took to align the picture,
making clean highlights easy to plot.
I've been looking forward for years to finding a good maze for markup.

Comment: An excellent answer, worthy of publication in the Wall Street Journal.

Comment: Hahaa, @Rand al'Thor, they'd have to change their name to _Wall **Path** Journal_

Comment: @humn The red portal is not a red herring though - it presents an alternative (and shorter) path out! S -> R -> Y -> Exit!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, unless I missed a wall somewhere (follow the red path, ignore the yellow)

> [image: solution]

Path:

> Start → Green
>  Green → Pink
>  Pink → Key
>  Key → Pink (backwards)
>  Pink → Green (backwards)
>  Green → Red
>  Red → Yellow
>  Yellow → Exit

Comment: Hmm looks like there was probably a mistake in the scanning, because there should've been only one correct solution to the maze...

Comment: Nice find, pfg! I should mention your alternative solution in my nonsolution.
@MrSiliconGuy , i did notice what might be a partly-darkened construction line ([click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ATFs.png))
that would indeed isolate the upper **R**ed portal.
If something like that is what happened you could mention it as a postscript in the puzzle statement and perhaps even credit pfg for finding an unintended solution.
I, for one, enjoy how tidbits about construction and surprises add to a puzzle's personality.

Comment: @humn if you zoom in to the same location on the original photo of the map, the line is clearly there. It looks like it didn't scan very well initially, especially near the joins of the pages, and lines had to be re-drawn afterwards, with that one missed.

Comment: You solved the mystery of the unintended solution, @Steve , good one!  (I'll write a quick comment to let MrSiliconGuy know.)

Comment: Hello again, @MrSiliconGuy , in case you don't already know, Steve solved the mystery of the unintended solution in [the comment above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99556/4-page-maze-ft-portals/100143?noredirect=1#comment286108_100143)